# What is the largest number such that the number formed by the first $n$ digits is divisible by $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

What is the largest number such that the number formed by the first $n$ digits is divisible by $n$?

For example, if we have a number $$abcdefghijklm,$$ and all of these leters stand for digits,
then $a$ is divisible by $1$, $ab$ is divisible by $2$, $abc$ is divisible by $3$, and so on. Also, what is allowed is (besides $a$) the digits can be $0$ and digits can repeat.

Comment: Cool question..

Comment: If you're gready, it feels like you get to $98765\ldots$?

Comment: As a side note, [numberphile](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaVMrqzb91w) just did a video where they mentioned a (the only) pan-digital polydivisible number, $3,\!816,\!547,\!290$.

Comment: Then, the earth will be destroyed the day 3/8/1654729 !!

Comment: I agree it's a duplicate, but the title is so much better...

Answer (score 3):

By copying and pasting the question, it turns out that these numbers are called polydivisible numbers, and there are finitely many of them, with the largest being:

$3608528850368400786036725$

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydivisible_number